# View not receiving tap events

Tags: objective-c, ios7, storyboard

Interface:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)dismissPopup {
    NSLog(@"popup view dismissed");
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
           shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    return touch.view == self.view;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissPopup)];

    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    //...
}
```

The dismiss method is never triggered, why? I am on iOS7, using storyboard.

---

Log of touch.view

```
MYAPP[5779:60b] <UIView: 0x17ecd8b0; frame = (0 0; 320 418);
 autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x17ecd910>>
```

self.view:

```
 MYAPP[5779:60b] <UIView: 0x17ecd590; frame = (0 64; 320 504);
 autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17eb2c70>; layer
 = <CALayer: 0x17ecd5f0>>
```

Log from debugger: http://dpaste.com/1768718/

Comment: this code working fine for me as i created `demo project -> copy -> run` in `Xcode 5` with `iOS 7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine on my end.

If you breakpoint in 
`gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` 
can you ensure that touch.view is actually self.view in your implementation?

Comment: Yes the breakpoint is triggered, however when I breakpoint the dismiss method nothing happens...

Comment: @artworkadシ, what I meant was, what's the output of both self.view and touch.view in the console?

Comment: I edited my question with log information, however not sure if it is the right information..

Comment: If you create a new project containing just the code you've posted, then it will work. Once you have this, then compare/contrast the two projects to find whatever is causing the problem.

Comment: You see why this doesn't work right? touch.view is not the same view as self.view, so your equality check in the gestureRecognizer delegate function is returning NO.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Well, you have to re-consider your equality check there. Which view are you actually trying to land on? Which views can you land on that should still fire the alert? it seems like your view hierarchy is not quite what you think it is. I highly recommend using Spark Inspector (http://sparkinspector.com/) and in that same breakpoint, take a closer look at what your view hierarchy looks like, and at what point you want that gesture recognizer to fire.